# Irrational, why can't C++ compiler report my exact error line number for std::max?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a simiple `stdmax.cpp` like this:

```
1. // 2023.06.03, Jimm's stdmax.cpp
2. #include <algorithm>
3. #include <stdio.h>
4.  
5. int main(int argc, char *argv[])
6. {
7.     printf("sizeof(void*) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(void*));
8.     printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
9.     printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
10.  
11.     int m = std::max(11, 22, 33); // cause compile error!
12.  
13.     return 0;
14. }
```

Using Visual C++ 2019, v16.11, the error reporting is:

[image]

Using gcc-12, the result is similar:

[image]

You see, neither of them told me the exact line number causing the compile-error.

Ideally, we should see `stdmax.cpp`'s line #11 in error messages, right? But we don't.

Could somebody help explain why is it so?

Comment: Read the documentation on [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), there is no overload with 3 arguments. But there is one with an initializer list. So it is std::max({11,22,33});. And no you don't have to see a .cpp, lot of api's are header file only (specialy for class/function templates).
Your code also looks to be a mix of "C" and "C++", so where are you learning C++ from?

Comment: How is `stdmax.cpp:11:21: required from here` not pointing at the exact location. There's just a decision being made to list the non-applicable overloads first.

Comment: Try `int m = std::max({11, 22, 33});`

Comment: The question is not true. All compilers show the compiled line in the next error message, GCC for example: `prog.cpp:11:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::max<int, int>' requested here
   int m = std::max(11, 22, 33); // cause compile error!`. I think OP misleads SO community with unknown aims, and has numbered lines in the code for making it harder to compile.

Comment: The OP is correct about the message from VS2019. However, VS2022 does point at the line in main. Perhaps a reason for an upgrade?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, positive or negative. Now I know, I was my flaw to neglect that gcc finally mumbles the error line number in its "required from here" message.

And I think it is irrational for those guys to vote down my question or even want to close it. I did investigation, and I clearly show you what I do and what I see. We need to admit,  quite a lot of questions result from our inadvertently neglecting some information which is inevitable by a human, then do all those question deserve down votes?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of SO user comments, now I can answer this question.

For gcc(at least from 7.5, many years ago), it does report my error lines, in its symbolic "required from here" message. You can just see it in the creenshot of my question.

```
./stdmax.cpp:11:32:   required from here
```

For Visual C++, we need a very new version, [released several weeks ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history).

VS2022 v17.6.2 (cl version `19.36.325322`) reports it correctly.

[image]

I also tried VS2022 v17.5.3, the same output as VS2019.